# How to load a pickle file containing a dictionary with unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary, pickle

I have a dictionary:

```
mydict={'öö':1,'ää':2}
```

I have written it to a pickle file:

```
a=codecs.open(r'mydict.pkl', 'wb', 'utf-8')
pickle.dump(mydict, a)
```

If I try to load it:

```
m=codecs.open(r'mydict.pkl', 'rb', 'utf-8')
mydict = pickle.load(m)
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: u"S'\\xe4\\xe4'\np1\nI2\nsS'\\xf6\\xf6'\np2\nI1\ns."
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pickle is a binary format, using codec translations before writing will break it. Try to just write to a file and loading it back:

```
>>> mydict={'öö':1,'ää':2}
>>> mydict
{'\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6': 1, '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa4': 2}
>>> pickle.dump(mydict, open('/tmp/test.pkl', 'wb'))
>>> pickle.load(open('/tmp/test.pkl', 'rb'))
{'\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6': 1, '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa4': 2}
```

But most probably you want to use Unicode in the first place:

```
>>> mydict={u'öö':1,u'ää':2}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is the use of `codecs.open`. Pickles are binaries not text and `codec` is for transparent conversion from some text encoding to unicode. You should just use `open` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Old issue but... I have had the same problem and I didn't think extra disk IO is a fine solution. I suggest you using base64 encode/decoding.

```
import base64

serialized_str = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(mydict))
my_obj_back = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(serialized_str))
```

Even cPickle could be used same way for faster results in batches.